# Simplify a mesh after using Array modifier

Tags: modifiers, curve-modifier

I'm trying to create a 3d object with nice detail to 3d print
using an *svg* file, an *Array Modifier*, and a *Curve*.

To get the best definition possible, I use 1500 small cubes to create the mesh and shape I want but it probably isn't the ideal approach.

Is there a way to simplify this mesh so the multiple squares aren't visible as seen in the image below? Is there another technique to achieve what I want?

[image]

Comment: It looks to me like this is an array->curve.  Why not just give the curve object some geometry/bevel at resolution 0 and use that?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to try this out in Geometry Nodes

You may want to look at this one "**Curve De-former Using Blender Geometry Nodes**"

https://youtu.be/sNpWs1xbNOU?t=581

[image: img1]